# Model has many attachables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an `Event` model which I'm looking to add a list of attachable models too. This needs to include some kind of polymorphism as the list of attachables can be any one of `Contact` `User` `Post` `Import` and a couple of others.

I'm not entirely sure of how I would best achieve this. A single contact can be attached to many events, too. Take the following, for example:

```
event.attachables #=> [User, Contact, Contact, Import, ...]
user = event.attachables.first
user.attached_events #=> [Event, Event, Event, ...]
```

Any points in the right direction for best achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked for the same thing yesterday.

I've found a blog post which describes everything in details and helped me implement this.

http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/Rails_polymprphic_has_many_through_relationships.html

The key thing here is to define the attribute `source` in the `has_many` declaration of your `event` model, and `as` in the `has_many` declarations of `Contact`, `User` and `Post`

You just need to find a proper, descriptive name for `source` :)

Comment: That seems like what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'd really recommend that you read this Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations. It covers exactly what you're after.

Comment: Right, except it's not that simple because it's not a one to many association. I have read the guides and I have implemented many polymorphic associations but this isn't the same because it's a many-to-many relationship so I am looking for advice on implementation.